# Add combobox in phpgrid

Tags: php, gridview, datagrid, phpgrid

I am developing a php websites where i need to add a combobox in a row of phpgrid.Just assume that a user will select his/her Company through a combobox value.[image]How to i do that ? Need suggestions badly.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From phpgrid documentation http://phpgrid.com/example/set_col_edittype-2/, you can set "autocomplete" edit type.

```
$dg -> set_col_edittype("officeCode", "autocomplete", "Select officeCode,city from offices",false);
```

[image]